# How do I get a substring of a string in Python using a recursive function?

Tags: python, function, recursion, recursive-query

I'm supposed to come up with 2 function.s I have type down a recursive function named find(text, substring). i want this function to return the substring inside the text, else return an empty string if subtsring is not inside the text. For second function i will define it as is_string_there(text, string) to test the find function. Then, the function will reutrn "True" if the string is inside the text or false if the string is not inside the text

Here is my code:

```
def find(text, substring):
  if substring == is_string_there:
    return is_string_there
  else:
    return null


def is_string_there(text, string):



print(is_string_there("I love DSAGx", "DSAGx"))
print(is_string_there("I love Python", "DSAGx"))
```

The output i'm trying to achieve:
True
False

Comment: Why would you want to use a recursive function for that *in python*? Aside from the operation being a builtin or standard-library function in pretty much every language, neither the language itself nor its data structures make recursion the first thing you *should* reach for in Python, unline e.g. functional languages based on linked lists.

Comment: Why do you want to do this unnecessary recursion. I don't see any productivity here. You can instead use ```in``` keyword as a one-liner solution to your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_string_there(text, string):
    return string in text
```

Comment: `return string in text` ? =)

Comment: Why didn't I think of that ;-D